# How set Expandable row in angularjs and datatable grid?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I have using datatable with angularjs.i wish get row detail like as https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html on click every rows.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="TodayCtrl">
    <table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="options" class="table table-striped m-b-none">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th  style="width:20%">Rendering engine</th>
                        <th  style="width:25%">Browser</th>
                        <th  style="width:25%">Platform(s)</th>
                        <th  style="width:15%">Engine version</th>
                        <th  style="width:15%">CSS grade</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
</div>
```

Angularjs:

```
app.controller('TodayCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http ) {
    $scope.options = {
        sAjaxSource: 'urlofjsondata',
        aoColumns: [
            { mData: 'engine' },
            { mData: 'browser' },
            { mData: 'platform' },
            { mData: 'version' },
            { mData: 'grade' }
        ]

    };

}]);
```

My data showing correctly as row wise in grid.But i wish to show info on row click .i am new in angular.please help thanks

Comment: Thank. i no need to open popup on click row ,but i wish add column on first like plus(+) and minus(-).if i click on that plus then data should be display on bottom of row

Comment: @FMC, what on earth have bootstrap anything to do with datatables and angular??

Comment: @davidkonrad Sorry I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to show more data as a popup when someone clicked on a row.